# Want to put a Java app that needs launch script onto the gnome / ubuntu-dock

Tags: gnome, 19.04, ubuntu-dock

I've been playing around with a `my-thing.desktop` config file for the last hour. I have a Java-based app (in a jar) which I need to launch with java. My goal is to get it with its icon on the dock.

Right now I can't even get it on the desktop!

This is what I have:

```
adam@ubuntu:~$ cat ~/Desktop/Umlet.desktop
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open                                                         
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_GB]=/home/adam/Umlet/img/umlet_logo.png
Name[en_GB]=Umlet
Exec=java -jar /home/adam/Umlet/umlet.jar
Name=Umlet
Icon=/home/adam/Umlet/img/umlet_logo.png
adam@ubuntu:~$
```

As said, I can't even get it to appear on the desktop. I've followed various answers to other similar questions recommending stuff like executing:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

but I didn't get any further. What do I need to do?

I'm not even sure I'm calling it the right thing. Can I call it the dash? In my Settings, it's Dock.

One probably important extra point: when I run the app, I see the app on the dash / dock, but unlike all the other icons, when I right-click on it, I **DO NOT** get the option to "add to favorites"
[image]

Just worked out that I am talking about the Ubuntu Dock, not the Unity Dash :O  due to the installed gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock package.

Comment: The Desktop is slowly dying on gnome. Put your `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` and see if it pops up in the application launcher.

Comment: OK, well that is a giant step for mankind. The icon appears in the app launcher. However I can't choose to have it in my favourites. The `Add to favorites` option on the right click menu is missing :(

Comment: Take a look at other `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` and make sure that your `.desktop` file has all attributes like `MimeType`, `Categories`, etc.